# What's the point of minifying JavaScript / CSS source if you enable Gzip on server?

Tags: javascript, gzip, minify

I never understood why is everyone minifying all the JS/CSS/HTML stuff when anyways when you enable Gzip on the server side, everything gets much higher compression over the wire... isn't this just counter productive?

tx for input

Sean

Answer (score 0):

Because it decrease size of javascript file and so it loads faster.

It's just one thing of a huge list developers do in order to optimize/tune websites.
F.x. you also may find that somebody merged few JS into 1 bigger JS file so instead of f.x. 5 requests you will get 1.
It's all about to deliver webpage to end-user faster.

Google likes fast website, so the faster your deliver page to end user the higher rank your pages will get.